# UINavigationController popViewControllerAnimated sluggish transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UINavigationController based application with multiple views in it.

I am seeing a little sluggish transition while I am popping back to previous view controller by calling below method on navigation controller. The only reason I can think of it in viewWillAppear of my view controller to which I am transitioning I am doing a little heavy stuff that takes a little more than a second. Is there any way to make transition in such a case little faster?

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

**EDIT:**
Few important things:

1. I am running on device.
2. I tried commenting out all the code from viewWillAppear but I get the same behavior.
3. The delay is observed only in iOS 7. Tried in iOS 6 and it seems to work fine there.

Comment: try profiling your app using the Time Profiler in Instruments and come back with more

Answer (score 19):

I know I am also a little late to the party, but I had a very similar issue where I had a header image taking up the whole width, that when popped it caused a nasty juddery effect on the view that was being popped to.

My fix was quite simple. I only needed to ensure that the top level View clipped its Subviews. As my View was designed in Interface Builder, it was just a matter of selecting the outer view container (the one with the thick border) and checking the "Clip Subviews" option.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I might be late but for the Googlers who get here:
If you happen to have a choppy user experience when leaving a view controller with fancy UI stuff like full scale background image try to add the following

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
...
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    self.view.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
}
```

It will flatten ur layer so its easier to process.

EDIT:
Or if ur really desperate:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, 0);
[self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageView *fakeBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:snapshot];
[[self.view  subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
[self.view addSubview:fakeBackground];
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things...

1) Are you using the simulator? Are you running Mavericks? I got drastic performance problems when I upgraded.

2) When it comes to view controllers... I try to keep as much out of viewWillAppear as possible. Override your init function and do most of your initialization in there. That way it starts earlier and isn't called any time. Only things that need to be called every time the controller appears should be put in there and that method should be lean.

Comment: Well, I am running on device and I tried commenting out all the code from viewWillAppear but I get the same behavior.

Comment: Okay then it sounds like something else. Like maybe you're allocating a bunch of view controllers for that navigation controller. You should only allocate them once. Also, there is a possibility if you have another chunk of code that's doing anything intense asynchronously it could be affecting the entire app.

Comment: Yes you are right. I am initializing multiple viewcontrollers because all of them are in the UIScrollView and we allow horizontal swipe on them. So, any workaround keeping the needed viewcontrollers active?

Comment: As long as you initialize and assign them one time they shouldn't go out of memory.

Something like...
self.navigationController.viewControllers = @[vc1, vc2, vc3];

Answer (score 0):

so you are blocking the main thread, thats the reason why the transition animation is jerky.
If those operations you do in viewwillappear are not related to UI,try to do those operations in another thread.

If those operations are related to UI,set a timer for .3 seconds, till the transition completes and then do the UI-related operations when timer fires (after animation completes).

Comment: I tried inducing a delay of 0.3 seconds for all my viewWillAppear activities but I got the same behavior.